# converting media type with ffmpeg

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ffmpeg, media

Can anyone help me convert media to m4v format. I guess ffmpeg would be a nice choice coz I have a rails application where I need to do the conversion. I google, but could not find the solution.

BTW I am using jplayer for playing video which only takes m4v video file and thats the reason I need to convert video submitted by user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what FFmpeg's designed to do.  You didn't specify the type of input media, but it should be as simple as:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file -o output.m4v
```